# ASP.NET Custom Control - DataBinding

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have my custom control inside of a formview.  This custom control has a variety of properties one of which is `Value` which I am trying to databind.

Using `Container.DataItem` I can databind my control, and **everything works**:

```
<fc:Literal runat="server" ID="readState" Label="State:" Value='<%# Container.DataItem("ActivityState") %>' />
```

Then when I try to databind using `Eval`, then it doesn't:

```
<fc:Literal runat="server" ID="readState" Label="State:" Value='<%# Eval("ActivityState") %>' />
```

Gives the Error:

> Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

Everything workds great with `Container.DataItem`, so my question is: Why does `Container.DataItem` work and `Eval` doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eval can only be used with templated controls.

> The Eval method evaluates late-bound
>   data expressions in the templates of
>   data-bound controls such as the
>   GridView, DetailsView, and FormView 
>   controls. At run time, the Eval 
>   method calls the Eval(Object, String) 
>   method of the DataBinder object,
>   referencing the current data item of
>   the naming container. The naming
>   container is generally the smallest
>   part of the data-bound control that
>   contains a whole record, such as a row
>   in a GridView control. You can
>   therefore use the Eval method only for
>   binding inside templates of a
>   data-bound control.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement/extend one of the server controls following to get databinding expression syntax:

Templated Databound Control: 
Couple of articles: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478964.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479322.aspx

CompositeDataboundControl: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.compositedataboundcontrol.aspx

DatBoundControl: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.databoundcontrol.aspx